# How can I interchange between multypling and dividing by 2 different numbers?

Tags: python, compare, multiplication, divide, interchange

I'm given integers **X**, **Y**, and **Z**.  In each step, I can either multiply or divide, by either 2 or 3.  I need to transform **X** to **Z** in exactly **Y** steps ... or determine that it's not possible.

For Example:

```
X is 9,
Y is 8,
Z is 4.
```

9 can become 4 by: 9/3/3x2x2x2x2/2/2 = 4
As you can see I made 8 operations.

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: @nevabyte How do you make 5 from 1 then?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The divisors are not arbitrary, they are either 2 or 3 or both.

Comment: @nevabyte Um, huh? But ok, ignore the 1 and make 5 using 2 and 3 then.

Comment: @nevabyte So? 1 isn't 5. Make **5**.

Comment: Um, what do you mean the "real" number for `2 / 3 * 3 ` is 1.99999999?

Comment: @nevabyte That long expression doesn't make 5 but 32768/6561. Try again? Btw, you did start from 1 after all, so why did you complain about that earlier?

Comment: @nevabyte Again, what do you mean **the real number?**. `2/3*3` is *exactly equal* to 2. Which happens to be *exactly equal* to `1.99999....` So again, what are you trying to get at?

Comment: @nevabyte Well show us how then.

Comment: @nevabyte I see what you are getting at now. Not sure of the validity, it's been a while since I did any analysis, but I know what you mean now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think nevabyte's idea works. If we apply logarithms, the problem becomes turning log(1)=0 into log(5) by adding ±log(2) and ±log(3). So now we're talking about a series like nevabyte did. Is that how you understood it as well? The problem is, there is no series with those terms that converges to log(5), or even converges at all. Because we're always jumping up or down by at least log(2). While we might **get** arbitrarily close to the goal, we can't **stay** close enough.

Comment: Same with multiplication (i.e., no log). We might **get** arbitrarily close to 5 with some prefix product, but the very next prefix product will be far away again, as we have to multiply or divide by at least 2. So we don't **stay** close enough to "converge" to 5.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use descriptive variable names, such as **start**, **target**, and **steps**.

No, there isn't an *easy* way to do this, but there are *straightforward* ways.

First, you need to find the necessary change.  Break down both **start** and **target** into factors of 2, factors of 3, and anything else.  If this "anything" else" doesn't match, then you can't solve the problem at all.

For instance, look at your given problem: going from 9 to 4.  Breaking down each number:

```
9 = 3*3    # no 2's, no other stuff
4 = 2*2    # no 3's, no other stuff
```

Since the "other" stuff matches (i.e. 1), you can make the transition.  You need to remove 2 factors of 3, and add 2 factors of 2.  That's 4 steps.  From there, all you have to do is add pairs of *3/3 or *2/2 until you have 8 steps.

Let's try with changing 56 into 126:

```
 56 = 2*2*2*7   # no 3's, other = 7
126 = 2*3*3*7   # other = 7
```

To make the transition, you need to remove two 2's and add two 3's.  That's four steps; you adjust to the desired number as before.

There's your attack; can you code that?

Comment: But what if I have 9 operations total and by the time I get to the target I'm one division or one multiplicacion short?

Comment: If you're short by an odd quantity of operations, you can't solve the problem as given.

Comment: Do you know the most efficient way to calculate the prime factors of a number? I try the: for x in range(2,number) and then asking if (number%x ==0) saving the numbers that enter the if in cuestion.

Comment: I already have the code done thanks to your tip, is just that my program just snaps when I enter a number > 3^15 :(

Comment: Most of all, note that you do *not* need a complete prime factorization: all you need is factors of 2 and 3.  As for primes in general, there's no one best way, but there are myriad solutions in the research you supposedly did before you posted.  Try "prime sieve".

Comment: Also, if you have a new problem with your code, please post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a brute-force approach *that scales horrifically* -- O(y^4),

```
def bruteforce(x, y, z, acc="", accv=None):
    if accv == z and len(acc) == y*2:
        return acc
    if accv is None:
        accv = x
    if len(acc) == y*2:
        return
    m2 = bruteforce(x, y, z, acc+'*2', accv*2)
    m3 = bruteforce(x, y, z, acc+'*3', accv*3)
    d2 = bruteforce(x, y, z, acc+'/2', accv/2)
    d3 = bruteforce(x, y, z, acc+'/3', accv/3)
    return m2 or m3 or d2 or d3
```

In action:

```
In [49]: exp = bruteforce(9, 8, 4)

In [50]: exp
Out[50]: '*2*2*2*2/2/2/3/3'

In [51]: eval('9'+exp)
Out[51]: 4.0

In [52]: exp = bruteforce(13, 8, 4)

In [53]: exp

In [54]: exp = bruteforce(9, 7, 2)

In [55]: exp
Out[55]: '*2*2*2/2/2/3/3'

In [56]: eval('9'+exp)
Out[56]: 2.0
```

Will be buggy because of floating-point inaccuracy...

Comment: For accuracy you could use `fractions.Fraction`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, the function should work if you just pass it `Fraction` objects, but boy does it slow down!